# What are IMPATT files?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

im looking in my /tmp folder and see tons of files named IMPATTXXXXXXXX where x is just random numbers and or letters. any one know what these files are? We are trying to clean out out VPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see this files are from the [horde](http://www.horde.org/)-framework (I just googled it, maybe its from something different) and can be safely removed. Anyway, usually nothing should *ever* write something more or less important into `/tmp`, thus you can usually delete everything in it.

Answer (score 0):

IMPATXXXX are related to IMP. This files are from attachments; they can be left behind if a user cancels a message after attaching files.